# Postgresql: order by two boolean and 1 timestamp columns

Tags: postgresql

Im having trouble with a query that becomes ghastly slow as the database grows.

The problem seems to be the sorting, which depends on three conditions - importance, urgency and timestamp.

The query currently in use is plain old 
ORDER BY urgent DESC, important DESC, date_published DESC

Fields are boolean for urgent and important, and date_published is an integer (UNIX timestamp).

Comment: Do you filter in addition to the ORDER BY? I suspect you can improve performance **a lot** more. Show the full query and we might find more.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple tables and conditions involved and the query minus the ordering runs under 20 ms. With the ordering it went up to nearly 4000 ms. With the suggestions for a compound index I actually created a 4 column index, and right now the query takes between 20 and 30 ms. Thanx all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON table_name (urgent DESC, important DESC, date_published DESC);
```

Comment: Yes, the nicest things in life are the simplest. The compound index has eluded me successfully. Thanks to bos and user unknown.

Comment: This was it for me, the order by and index needed to match exactly!

Answer (score 4):

Create indexes for columns you sort by regularly. You may even set a compound index.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. All three columns have indexes.